# Авторизация в OAuth + Google + scribejava

Tags: java, oauth

Все прикрутил и пример вставил, даже реализовал веб-проект. Но все время возвращает `body=null`.

Вот код-класс для авторизации:

```
package com.dj.kz.djooga.users.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import com.github.scribejava.apis.GoogleApi20;
import com.github.scribejava.core.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth2AccessToken;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.Response;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.Verb;
import com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service;

public class UserAuthService {

    private OAuth20Service service;
    private String clientId = "1938140...";
    private String secretId = "MCLXS...";
    private String callback = "http://localhost:8080/djooga-webapp-admin/main";
    private String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";

    private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
    private OAuth2AccessToken accessToken;

    public UserAuthService(String authService) {

        switch (authService) {
        case "google":
            service = new ServiceBuilder(clientId).apiSecret(secretId).callback(callback).scope(scope)
                    .build(GoogleApi20.instance());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public String getUserInfo(String code) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException {

        this.accessToken = service.getAccessToken(code);
        OAuthRequest rqs = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, rqs);
        Response res = service.execute(rqs);
        return res.toString();
    }

    public String getAuthURL() {
        if (service != null)
            return service.getAuthorizationUrl();
        else
            return "/error";
    }
}
```

Вот, что возвращает метод `getUserInfo`:

```
Response{code=200, message='OK', body='null', headers={Transfer-
Encoding=chunked, null=HTTP/1.1 200 OK, Alt-Svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; 
v="39,38,37,35", Server=GSE, X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, Date=Wed, 20 
Sep 2017 03:07:32 GMT, Accept-Ranges=none, X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN, 
Cache-Control=private, max-age=0, Vary=Accept-Encoding, Expires=Wed, 20 Sep 
2017 03:07:32 GMT, X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block, Content-Type=text/plain}}
```

Сервлет на всякий случай:

```
package com.dj.kz.djooga.webapp.admin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.dj.kz.djooga.users.service.UserAuthService;

public class MainServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.print("ok");

        String code = request.getParameter("code");

        if (code!=null) {            
            UserAuthService uas = new UserAuthService("google");
            System.out.println("code");
            String ui="";
            try {
                ui = uas.getUserInfo(code);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                super.forward("/jsp/error.jsp", request, response);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                super.forward("/jsp/error.jsp", request, response);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            request.setAttribute("userInfo", ui);
            super.forward("/jsp/welcom.jsp", request, response);
        }
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session.getAttribute("userId") == null) {
            String url;
            if (request.getSession().getAttribute("uas") == null) {
                UserAuthService uas = new UserAuthService("google");
                request.getSession().setAttribute("uas", uas);
                url = uas.getAuthURL();

            } else {
                url = ((UserAuthService) request.getSession().getAttribute("uas")).getAuthURL();
            }
            request.setAttribute("authUrl", url);
            super.forward("/jsp/auth.jsp", request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

И еще один вопрос: при авторизации надо сохранить `tocken`?